# Exchange server redirect email to another smtp

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2016

Does anyone know if it's possible to redirect email received to Exchange server 2016 to external SMTP MTA?

For example everything received from domain.com to be redirected to encryption gateway. So that not all email is going trough said gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You do this with send connectors. If you only want one domain to go through the send connector, you modify the "Address space" for the connector.

[Official Microsoft documentation has greater details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/outbound-smart-host-routing?view=exchserver-2016).

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to confirm your requirement: Do you want to redirect emails which are sent from certain domain(e.g. domain.com) to your Exchange 2016 Server to external?

If so, you could try to create a transport rule(Condition: If the sender's domain is "domain.com", action: Redirect the message to an external email address) to redirect emails.